# kubuntu 11.10 okular annotations save folder-files

Tags: kubuntu, okular

I have a problem with a laptop that has kubuntu 11.10 and I am going to format it. The problem is that I have many Okular annotations stored in and I can't find where Okular stores them so I can get a backup. Anyone knows exactly where are annotations being stored?
 Is it possible to store them in a Dropbox folder and link Okular to that folder so I can share the annotations with all my computers? How can I do that? I have found a similar thread to superuser.com but it didn't help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried saving a ´´document archive´´ from the open document by choosing File --> Export As --> Document Archive?

Comment: Doesnt this mean i have to do it for every document i have? Seems to work if u have 2-3 docs only. I add annotations to ebooks almost every day so it would be awesome to share the annotation save file in a dropbox folder so evey pc that i own can automatically sync the annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To share an annotated document with someone else, you'll need to
>   export it as an Okular document archive from the File menu.

The annotations are kept in `/home/username/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`.

Hope that this will help.

<sup>Source: [wilderssecurity](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/archive/index.php/t-313803.html)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but how can i link okular to save docdata to a custom folder? lets say /home/username/dropbox/docdata ?

Comment: Is this what i have to do : `sudo ln -s /home/username/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata /home/username/dropbox/docdata` I have to link the new destination somehow right?

Comment: You must move the actual docdata folder into Dropbox, and then create a symlink in ~/.kde/share/apps/okular.  If you do it the other way around, Dropbox will erase the symlink with the actual directory, and nothing will be synced anymore.  So, e.g.: `mv ~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata ~/Dropbox && ln -s ~/Dropbox/docdata ~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks blujay! I can finally have my annotations everywhere without carrying paper. Make sure the "destination" computer also has an empty docdata directory before linking.

Comment: @GeoPapas: Why `sudo`?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Not sure but just in case `ln` wont work without it.